# Valgrind reports uninitialised value(s) in sqlite3_step

Tags: c++, sqlite, valgrind

I'm writing a multithreaded C++ app that writes data to sqlite database. One thread does the database stuff and others gather data or update display, so there is no multithreaded use of the database or sqlite functions. My problem is that Valgrind Memcheck gives following output on use of uninitialised values in database thread (**update:** please see output with full debug info in the end):

```
Thread 6:
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==15356==    at 0x35A7A0C7FE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A6994E: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A5655F: sqlite3_step (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x478CE2: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
    ... (rest of the call stack)

(previous section two more times)

Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
    ==15356==    at 0x35956DB79D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A1E8BD: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A16ECE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A25EC3: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A26178: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A3C16E: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A6C915: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A5655F: sqlite3_step (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x47B470: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:721)
    ... (rest of the call stack - no space between these outputs)
Address 0x4ed2a88 is 1,208 bytes inside a block of size 1,280 alloc'd
    ==15356==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A1DD61: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A09368: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A09447: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A0AC9A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A241FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A17825: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A272FE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A27477: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A274DE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A277D9: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A27871: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==15356==    at 0x35A7A0C7FE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A6994E: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A5655F: sqlite3_step (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x47B470: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:721)
    ... (rest of the call stack)

(previous section two more times)

Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
    ==15356==    at 0x35956DB79D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A1E8BD: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A287A6: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A376E7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A37906: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A38443: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A6FC80: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A5655F: sqlite3_step (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A59AC5: sqlite3_exec (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x48EDBD: MyClass::commitTransaction() (MyClass.h:659)
    ... (rest of the call stack - no space between these outputs)
Address 0x4ed2a88 is 1,208 bytes inside a block of size 1,280 alloc'd
    ==15356==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A1DD61: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A09368: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A09447: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A0AC9A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A241FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A17825: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A272FE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A27477: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A274DE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A277D9: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
    ==15356==    by 0x35A7A27871: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)

(and so on ...)
```

First two of the code sections pointed in the Valgrind output are in the same function and the third is an inline function called from that function. First code section (MyClass.cpp:576) pointed in the Valgrind output is like this:

```
// get statement pointer
stmtPtr = getStatementPtr(STATEMENT_INDEX_FOR_THIS_OPERATION);

// reset prepared statement and clear bindings (resetting MUST also be done
// after use - else lock on the database is not released!)
sqlite3_reset(stmtPtr);
sqlite3_clear_bindings(stmtPtr);

// bind directory data to the statement
sqlite3_bind_int(stmtPtr, 1, intValue);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 2, longIntValue1);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 3, longIntValue2);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmtPtr, 4, stdString.c_str(), stdString.length(),
                  SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 5, longIntValue3);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 6, longIntValue4);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 7, longIntValue5);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 8, longIntValue6);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmtPtr, 9, longIntValue7);

// execute statement
result = sqlite3_step(stmtPtr);                             <= line 576

// handle errors
if (result != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    // clean up
    cleanUp();      

    ... (error handling code)
}

// reset statement (MUST be done after use - else lock on the database is
// not released!)
sqlite3_reset(stmtPtr);
```

Second code section referenced in the Valgrind output (line 721) is simpler - there are only two long int values I bind, otherwise it's similar.

I'm storing statement pointers in a map like this: `std::map<STATEMENT_INDEX, sqlite3_stmt*> statements_;` and reuse them. Every time I use a prepared statement I first reset it and then clear bindings. Then I bind values to statement and call sqlite3_step(). After handling unexpected outcomes I reset the statement again to release lock on the database. Function cleanup() finalises statements and clears the map.

Third code section (MyClass.h:659) is an inline function that commits the transaction. This is called in the end of the function where the first two sections are in. In the beginning of the function I start transaction with similar inline function.

```
inline void MyFunction::commitTransaction()
{
    // sqlite error handling variables
    int result;
    char* errMsg = 0;

    // execute
    result = sqlite3_exec(database_,
                          "COMMIT TRANSACTION",
                          0,
                          0,
                          &errMsg);                 <= line 659

    // handle errors
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::string error = std::string(errMsg);
        sqlite3_free(errMsg);
        clearStatements();
        throw MyException("Committing transaction failed: '" + error
                          + "'!"LOCATION_LINE);
    }

    // set flag
    transactionOn_ = false;
}
```

I have checked with debugger that the values I bind to the statement are really initialised before the sqlite3_step() call. I also tried if it would make any difference to use local copies of all of the values being bound and to change SQLITE_STATIC to SQLITE_TRANSIENT. These changes had no effect. By the way, is it ok to bind references?

I also thought the possibility of statement pointer being finalized in some point before. Finalizing statements is only done through a function that finalizes all statements in the map and also clears the map. And when the map is empty statements are prepared again. So I don't think this can be the solution either.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the cause of the Valgrind output above? Or can someone explain why Valgrind gives the same output multiple times for the same incidence?

I debugged the program using vgdb server and setting breakpoints just before lines mentioned in the Valgrind output. After I continue after the first breakpoint I get: `Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.` and the Valgrind output for the line. This is what I was expecting. However when I continue after this break I get the same SIGTRAP (and outputs) two more times and with same function parameters for MyFunction. Why is this?

**update:** I compiled the latest version of sqlite3.c (3.8.5) with my code to get full debug info. This changed the errors reported a bit and cleared why Valgrind gave me "same" output multiple times. Actually it wasn't the same, silly me! So, here is Valgrind output with full debug info:

```
==1205== Thread 6:
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDF8E: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64529)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFC4: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64536)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFD1: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64537)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE098: sqlite3VdbeSerialTypeLen (sqlite3.c:64561)
==1205==    by 0x4D6421: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70150)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1205==    at 0x4CE0A9: sqlite3VdbeSerialTypeLen (sqlite3.c:64565)
==1205==    by 0x4D6421: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70150)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4D6490: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70162)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDF8E: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64529)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFC4: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64536)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFD1: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64537)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4D6605: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70199)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE0CC: sqlite3VdbeSerialPut (sqlite3.c:64639)
==1205==    by 0x4D6673: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70200)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE14A: sqlite3VdbeSerialPut (sqlite3.c:64658)
==1205==    by 0x4D6673: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70200)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4D5D49: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:69927)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE098: sqlite3VdbeSerialTypeLen (sqlite3.c:64561)
==1205==    by 0x4D5DB2: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:69934)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1205==    at 0x4CE0A9: sqlite3VdbeSerialTypeLen (sqlite3.c:64565)
==1205==    by 0x4D5DB2: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:69934)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE193: sqlite3VdbeSerialGet (sqlite3.c:64689)
==1205==    by 0x4D5FED: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:69990)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1205==    at 0x4CE19C: sqlite3VdbeSerialGet (sqlite3.c:64689)
==1205==    by 0x4D5FED: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:69990)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==1205==    at 0x35956DB79D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
==1205==    by 0x4A980E: seekAndWriteFd (sqlite3.c:27173)
==1205==    by 0x4A9886: seekAndWrite (sqlite3.c:27193)
==1205==    by 0x4A999A: unixWrite (sqlite3.c:27260)
==1205==    by 0x49FEF6: sqlite3OsWrite (sqlite3.c:15755)
==1205==    by 0x4B3103: subjournalPage (sqlite3.c:44215)
==1205==    by 0x4B4B96: pager_write (sqlite3.c:45624)
==1205==    by 0x4B4E57: sqlite3PagerWrite (sqlite3.c:45737)
==1205==    by 0x4C4A27: sqlite3BtreeDelete (sqlite3.c:58313)
==1205==    by 0x4D8C1E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:71654)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==  Address 0x4cae77a is 986 bytes inside a block of size 1,280 alloc'd
==1205==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==1205==    by 0x4A086C: sqlite3MemMalloc (sqlite3.c:16359)
==1205==    by 0x4A1276: mallocWithAlarm (sqlite3.c:19730)
==1205==    by 0x4A1311: sqlite3Malloc (sqlite3.c:19763)
==1205==    by 0x4ADE35: pcache1Alloc (sqlite3.c:38393)
==1205==    by 0x4ADFCF: pcache1AllocPage (sqlite3.c:38477)
==1205==    by 0x4AEA16: pcache1Fetch (sqlite3.c:38985)
==1205==    by 0x4AD38E: sqlite3PcacheFetch (sqlite3.c:37805)
==1205==    by 0x4B4374: sqlite3PagerAcquire (sqlite3.c:45197)
==1205==    by 0x4BBE66: btreeGetPage (sqlite3.c:52758)
==1205==    by 0x4C143E: allocateBtreePage (sqlite3.c:56424)
==1205==    by 0x4C4F57: btreeCreateTable (sqlite3.c:58509)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4D6490: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70162)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4D6605: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70199)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47E041: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:722)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFF4: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64539)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CDFF4: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64539)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE008: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64540)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE019: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64541)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE030: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64542)
==1205==    by 0x4D640E: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70149)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE008: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64540)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE019: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64541)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1205==    at 0x4CE030: sqlite3VdbeSerialType (sqlite3.c:64542)
==1205==    by 0x4D65F7: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:70198)
==1205==    by 0x4D0924: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:66192)
==1205==    by 0x4D0B28: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:66258)
==1205==    by 0x47B8B3: MyClass::MyFunction(...) (MyClass.cpp:576)
==1205== 
==1205== 
==1205== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1205==     in use at exit: 6,976,167 bytes in 115,360 blocks
==1205==   total heap usage: 3,276,840 allocs, 3,161,480 frees, 467,886,044 bytes allocated
```

As I examine the first error in gdb, the variable i, that the conditional jump is based on, seems to be initialised:

```
(gdb) p pMem->u
$2 = {i = 0, nZero = 0, pDef = 0x0, pRowSet = 0x0, pFrame = 0x0}
```

So I'm still puzzled. Here's the function:

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE u32 sqlite3VdbeSerialType(Mem *pMem, int file_format){
  int flags = pMem->flags;
  int n;

  if( flags&MEM_Null ){
    return 0;
  }
  if( flags&MEM_Int ){
    /* Figure out whether to use 1, 2, 4, 6 or 8 bytes. */
#   define MAX_6BYTE ((((i64)0x00008000)<<32)-1)
    i64 i = pMem->u.i;                          <= i = 0
    u64 u;
    if( i<0 ){                                  <= line 64529
      if( i<(-MAX_6BYTE) ) return 6;
      /* Previous test prevents:  u = -(-9223372036854775808) */
      u = -i;
    }else{
      u = i;
    }
    if( u<=127 ){
      return ((i&1)==i && file_format>=4) ? 8+(u32)u : 1;
    }
    if( u<=32767 ) return 2;
    if( u<=8388607 ) return 3;
    if( u<=2147483647 ) return 4;
    if( u<=MAX_6BYTE ) return 5;
    return 6;
  }
  if( flags&MEM_Real ){
    return 7;
  }
  assert( pMem->db->mallocFailed || flags&(MEM_Str|MEM_Blob) );
  n = pMem->n;
  if( flags & MEM_Zero ){
    n += pMem->u.nZero;
  }
  assert( n>=0 );
  return ((n*2) + 12 + ((flags&MEM_Str)!=0));
}
```

Comment: Compile `sqlite3.c` together with your program so that you get proper debug information.

Comment: @CL. I'll have to try that on Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. After browsing (again) some similar questions in Stackoverflow i found that you can use option `--track-origins=yes` with Valgrind to track the origin of the uninitialised value. Using the option I got this new output from Valgrind:

```
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==6050==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==6050==    by 0x458AC2: MyOtherClass::MyOtherFunction(...) (MyOtherClass.cpp:378)
```

By investigating further I found that there were two unsigned longs in a datatype that I bound some of the variables from, that didn't get initialised *in the constructor*. However these variables were set *after* the object of this type was created *into heap using new*. There was never a situation that uninitialised values would have been really used, and this made it so hard to see where the problem was.